# why does nullish coalescing executing two parts?

Tags: javascript, nullish-coalescing

I have a method:

```
const objT2 = {
  calcAge(year) {
    console.log(2022 - year);
  },
};
```

but when I use the nullish coalescing both parts is being executed.

```
objT2.calcAge(1990) ?? console.log(`method not found`);
//output => 32    method not found
```

Comment: Calling `calcAge(1990)` doesn't `return` anything, so by default `undefined` is returned. The second opreand of `??` is evaluated if the first operand (ie: the return value of `calcAge()`) is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Logging and returning are two different things. Logging is a side-effect the occurs as part of running your function, returning is the actual value that your function "outputs"/evaluates to once called. Maybe you meant to do: `return 2022 - year` instead of `console.log(2022 - year)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you are calling `calcAge` method with `1990`. so by calling it, the method gets executed `objT2.calcAge(1990)`. this calculated `2022 - 1990` which is `32` and then logs it to the console. then this method returns `undefined` which gets evaluated as the left hand operand of the `??` operator. As this operator sees the left hand side is returning a nullish value (null or undefined), it goes on to execute the right hand side which logs `method not found` as well.